# How does Python exponentiate?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cython, precision, cpython

According to [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/36691/38029), (1) `a ** b` is numerically computed via (2) `exp(b * log(a))`, let's say at least for float, real and positive `a` & `b`. *Or does it?* I don't suppose complex and negatives are also handled this way. My ultimate question is whether (2) confers any numeric precision or stability advantage over (1), which is 'no' if they're same, and the answer lies in CPython but I don't know where exactly.

How does Python compute `a ** b`?

Comment: When you say "advantage over (1)", how are you imagining (1) is computed?

Comment: @kaya3 No clue, but test script [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/36687/38029) shows not much difference.